# how to create http transport business/proxy service in OSB

Tags: osb

I have a servlet end point (POST method) which returns byte array as response. I need to create a business service and proxy service in OSB.
Could some one help how I can do this using JDeveloper?

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the service, in the components tab you must choose the "HTTP". When you drag the HTTP component to the business services side, JDeveloper shows you an assistant in order to help you with the component configuration. In the second step, you must choose the type Messaging and specify the type of the request and the response, as you said the response must be binary for supporting the byte array.

In the last step you can define the end-point url...

Once created, in the "Transport Details" configuration tab, you can define the rest of connection details.

With this business service, you can invoke to the servlet. In order to offer this service in the OSB you must to create a proxy service, but depends on the type of the service you want to offer you must choose a component...